# Expo: “Error: Couldn’t get GCM token on device”

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, expo

SDK Version: 37.0.0

Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android

I’m trying to get a notification token to use in Expo Notifications, but i’m getting the following error:

“Error: Couldn’t get GCM token on device”.

I’ve already tried to update expo-cli . I updated my SDK version and nothing works!
I did the expo login in Expo Client App and in terminal and nothing too.
I restart my PC, SmartPhone, clean cache and nothing want to work!
I configurate the firebase like this -> 
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-fcm/ and nothing

I look for all the probably resolutions in expo forum and in Stack's frum. I try all, but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Possible solution:**

I did a test with a standalone app now, where i generate a .apk file from expo platform.

So, i put a “alert” on my code to show the comportament of my application: i was trying to know if the expo can get the token.

Apparently it’s a problem with the development environment and when we generate a apk, the expo can get the notficiation token and this yellow box with the message is showed only in development ambient.

Solution: generate a standalone app (apk) and put a alert to check if is possible the get the token and put a response here.

I wish that every users can get this solution!